# Why does implicitly casting a double to an IPAddress reverse the byte order?

Tags: .net, powershell, ip-address

Whilst writing a routine to generate a list of IPs in a given range (CIDR), I stumbled across a trick for reversing the bytes in the IP; casting the IP to a double then back.

i.e. running

```
$ip = '172.0.0.1'
[System.Net.IpAddress][Double]([System.Net.IpAddress]$ip).Address
```

Seems to be identical to running:

```
$ip = '172.0.0.1'
[byte[]]$bytes = ([System.Net.IpAddress]$ip).GetAddressBytes()
[Array]::Reverse($bytes)
[System.Net.IpAddress]($bytes -join '.')
```

However, using the same value but not casting to a double returns the original value (as one would expect).  Casting to a double doesn't seem to impact the value; only the type; so I don't think there's anything clever going on with the underlying maths.. So I assumed there was code to handle the `double`'s implicit conversion; but I can't see anything obvious in [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/system/Net/IPAddress.cs).

I've browsed but have so far been unable to find any documentation about this behaviour.

Specifically my question is: is this behaviour by design / can it always be relied upon to reverse the byte order of any given IP, or is it a trick that  will only work in specific scenarios?

Comment: Would you really want to leave code for future maintainers that makes *them* wonder what you were thinking when you've already got code that makes *clear* what the intention is (i.e. to reverse the bytes, using a method called Reverse seems quite obvious)?

Comment: That's a very good point; thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever.

Answer (score 1):

**There is a bit of a misunderstanding going on here**

You are not converting `$ip` to a `[Double]`, you are converting `$ip.Address`, which happens to be a `[Long]` and easily convertible to `[Double]`.

The resulting value is then used to create a new `[IPAddress]`. It appears this is done with `IPAddress.Parse`

The reason is because of [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence?view=powershell-7.1), member access comes before casting.

Effectively, your code is:

```
$ip = '172.0.0.1'
[System.Net.IpAddress] ([Double](([System.Net.IpAddress]$ip).Address))
# same as
[System.Net.IpAddress]::Parse(([Double]([System.Net.IpAddress]$ip).Address).ToString())
```

Which should have been fairly obvious given that the result wasn't a `[Long]`

Comment: Sadly those 2 results aren't the same.  The output is `1.0.0.172`, `172.0.0.1`.

Comment: Ah good spot; so Parse gives the same output for all types where the value is numeric (even if the type itself isn't).  But Parse given a numeric value will always reverse the byte order, whilst new will always keep the original.  There seems to be a comment implying that this reversal's expected, but the code's too complex for me to understand if this behavior's by design / why it's this way: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/system/Net/IPAddress.cs,300